# Как изменить действие при ON UPDATE/ON DELETE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как изменить действие при `ON UPDATE/ON DELETE`?

Вот как выглядит таблица сейчас:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_order` FOREIGN KEY (`order_idorder`)
REFERENCES `order` (`idorder`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

А вот такой запрос я делаю:

```
ALTER TABLE `orders`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_order` FOREIGN KEY (`order_idorder`) 
REFERENCES `order` (`idorder`) ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Получаю ошибку.

Как исправить, или что не так делаю?

Comment: А вы перед этим старый констраинт удаляете `alter table orders drop foreign key FK_orders_order` ?

Comment: @Mike да, удаляю, вот что пишет когда вставляю новый ` Ошибка SQL (1005): Can't create table 'exchange.#sql-1588_9' (errno: 150)

Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed *`

Comment: @Mike Если я создаю заного констраинт `(NO ACTION или RESTRICT) `то он создается а если делаю то что мне нужно `(CASCADE или SET NULL)` то кидает ошибку

Comment: А вы уверены, что MySQL поддерживает `on update`. в справочнике сказано только про `on delete`  http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SEC451.html

Comment: @Mike, в [оригинальной доке](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) есть

Comment: @rodgers, укажите пожалуйста `CREATE TABLE ...` для обеих таблиц, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: @rodgers, [похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106756/create-table-fails-with-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed)

Comment: @MaxU вот код выложил сюда-> https://privnote.com/pjaWKOqY#OaDaHw6u1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сделать `SET NULL` для столбца с `NOT NULL` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `idorders` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_idorder` INT(11) NOT NULL,      /* !!! NOT NULL constraint !!! */
    ...
```

Comment: Нет, длина , и тип данных одинаковы

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема решена